ADF-Tick or Untick the First Row as header in a Dynamic Dataset based upon the table

we use a generic dataset to move two csv file to externally control file and the actual data file (ctl & Dat)

In the Sink we use a generic dataset as shown above

The ctl file, header, should not, be sent to customer, whereas the Dat file, header should be, sent to the customer? Is there a sort of toggle or script to switch on / off based on the filename?
I can resolve it by switching off for both the ctl and dat. but making a change in SQL script to add headers, along with the actual data, any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

You can make the "First row as header" flag dynamic. If you hover over the checkbox in the dataset, the "Add dynamic content" link will appear:

Click that and use a Dataset Parameter to control the value. Then you supply the parameter value in the pipeline, so you can change it based on your file name pattern at runtime.

The Ctl file, header, should not, be sent to customer, whereas the Dat file, header should be, sent to the customer
By the above statement , it seems you want to remove the header itself from the Ctl file. That's not how first row as header works. It will just create dummy col names in case you turn off the 'first row as header' option.
This is how 'First row as header' option works:
When it's checked:
Id,Name,Country

1,'abc','US'

When not checked:
col_1,col_2,col_3
Id,Name,Country
1,'abc','US'

To achieve your requirement , you can use dataflow and perform the transformation of removing the header by using conditional split transformation and sink transformation .
